# Are there any desktop IM apps that I can download for Outlook2016?

Tags: office365, office365-apps, outlook-2016

I have search for about an hour trying to find an app or add-in so that I can Instant Message with my team.

Are there any Instant Messaging apps or add-ins for Outlook2016/Office365 that can be used on the desktop?

I know I can login to the web portal and message that way but that would make it an inconvenience for everyone.

When I click on the peoples tab in Outlook2016, by their name there are image options for IM, Call, Video, and Email but only the Email button is clickable.

Does anyone have any suggestions if they are using and Instant Messenger?

Please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Those features are in the Skype for Business client (formerly Office Communicator and Lync).  The contextual actions in Outlook would work with the default application that is registered in Windows to handle those actions, so when you install Skype they'll light up.